# What is the particle-hole asymmetry in superconductors? How is it manifested in the Yu-Shiba-Rusinov (YSR) states spectrum?

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity, many-body

[image]

I am really confused by the asymmetric peaks in YSR spectrum (source Nano Lett. 2021, 21, 16, 6748–6755). From the figure you can see the two peaks have different heights, which is caused by the particle-hole asymmetry. Is there anybody can explain to me what is the reason for this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: what is the source of the image?

Comment: Nano Lett. 2021, 21, 16, 6748–6755
Publication Date:August 5, 2021
https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.nanolett.1c00387